# Start RxJava2 Observable.interval() with no initial delay?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2, reactivex

I'm using a RxJava2 Observable to repeat an operation every second and later post the results to a TextView in my Android layout. The code I have right now (below) is working great, but I would rather have it execute with no initial delay.

```
Disposable disposable = Observable.interval(1000, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(aLong -> myMethod());
```

I've noticed that others using RxJS have used `timer()` instead of `interval()` to achieve 0 delay. Is there any way to do this with RxJava2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>There is a [Observable.timer(long delay, TimeUnit unit, Scheduler scheduler)](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/Observable.java#L3845) in [RxJava 2](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava). You can try using that.</strike>

**Update 1:**
For an [interval](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html) that starts with an initial delay and then emits on a regular interval, you can use [Observable.interval(long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit, Scheduler scheduler)](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/Observable.java#L2121)

Comment: I've tried doing this, but the task doesn't repeat. Correct me if I'm wrong, but Observable.timer() is for a one-time delay and Observable.interval() is what you would use to repeat a task multiple times.